# Dynamic content changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, dynamic

I want to create this:
[Multi Image Change](http://www.tchibo.de/cafissimo-latte-p400057196.html)

If you click on the Color picker Tumbnail("Farbe:"), other Pic will appear in the 
"pvImagesContent" section. I tried this on my self:

http://m4terialrmk.bplaced.net/list%20zoomer/demo.html

So far so good but now I cant figure out how to go on? I tried to put the several list zoom control in a div and make one appear and another disappear, but it broke my functionality.

Or must I just change the image path with help of Javascript? If so, I just want to change a section of the img path.

> img/**red**/pic-1.jpg >>will be>> img/**blue**/pic-1.jpg

Comment: Just so you know, _JavaScript_ and _Java_ are two completely different languages. Read this for more info: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: of what i get from your problem. you should change the src of you image on the basis of the click on the thumbnail. Also load all the images on page load itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('/red/')) ($(this).attr('src')).replace("/red/","/blue/");
    });
});
```